# Is it possible to use proxy chain in socket

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I want to know if you can use multiple proxy instead of one proxy for socket adn if you can how. i try some code but i not sure if that is right or not

Example code:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9050))

s.send(b'CONNECT 174.77.111.196:4145 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 174.77.111.196:4145\r\n\r\n')
s.recv(1000)

s.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n')
s.recv(5000)
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 3 proxy, A,B,C ...to create a tunnel to HTTP proxy B you just use:

```
CONNECT B_host:B_port HTTP/1.0
200 connections established
```

Then you have a tunnel to proxy B , passing from proxy A. Inside this tunnel you then can create another tunnel to target C:

```
CONNECT C_host:C_port HTTP/1.0
200 connections established
```

Remeber : not all proxies allow you to connect to hosts and ports.